# A portable regular expression for matching alphanumerics

Tags: c++, regex, encoding, ebcdic

I'm thinking about using the regular expression `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` to match any alphanumeric string in the C++ standard library's regular expression library.

But I'm worried about portability. Sure, in an ASCII character set, this will work, and I think that `0-9` *must* match only digits in any encoding system since the standard insists that all encodings have this property. But the C++ standard doesn't insist on ASCII encoding, so my a-zA-Z part might give me strange results on some platforms; for example those with EBCDIC encoding.

I could use `\d` for the digit part but that also matches Arabic numerals.

What *should* I use for a fully portable regular expression that only matches digits and English alphabet letters of either case?

Comment: What can be more portable than `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` that *matches digits and English alphabet letters of either case*? What strings do you intend to match?

Comment: Could it not be the case that `a-z` contains other things in that range? EDCBIC does. Or am I just confused?

Comment: The default syntax is ECMAScript. It does not support collations I believe. If you are going to use that in Cygwin, then yes, there may be a trouble (but you can always set `LC_COLLATE` to `C` (on Cygwin, done with `export`), it will give the expected results.

Comment: I think you need to tag this question with `EDCBIC` (or  is it `ebcdic`?) tag or just narrow it down a bit. C++ standard regex library can deal with the character class you mentioned.

Comment: There isn't an EDCBIC tag, so I've put the encoding one in instead.

Comment: I guess it is `EBCDIC` and it exists.

Comment: EBCDIC ? Are you programming on an IBM AS/400 ? Well I guess it is not portable then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PCRE (the current version of which is PCRE2) has support for other encoding types, including EBCDIC.

Within the source code on their website, I found "[this file](http://vcs.pcre.org/pcre2/code/tags/pcre2-10.00/src/pcre2_chartables.c.dist?revision=183&view=markup)" with the following (formatting mine):

> A program called dftables (which is distributed with PCRE2) can be used to build alternative versions of [this file](http://vcs.pcre.org/pcre2/code/tags/pcre2-10.00/src/pcre2_chartables.c.dist?revision=183&view=markup). This is necessary if you are running in an EBCDIC environment, or if you want to default to a different encoding, for example ISO-8859-1. When dftables is run, it creates these tables in the current locale. If PCRE2 is configured with `--enable-rebuild-chartables`, this happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're worried about supporting an exotic encodings, you can just list *all* characters manually:

```
[0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+
```

This looks *a bit* dirty, but surely it will work everywhere.